# How can I disable ts ts(2339) warning in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode. How Can I disable warning like this:

`Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type 'never'. ts(2339)`

[image: image warning]

It's always show on `*.vue` file

Comment: you can add comment above the line: `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: It's not just javascript code. It showing warning on html-vue too.